# How to make a sample file with Handbrake

Tags: macos, video-encoding, handbrake

I want to test a couple things with my encode before I encode the whole file. Is there a way for me to make a sample file (30 seconds long or something like that) that I can analyse using different applications (not just the built in sample preview).

By the way, I'm using the OSX Handbrake. Alternatively, the question can be stated as: "Where does handbrake store the short sample video files after creating them?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Handbrake previews are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Handbrake/Previews` in a subfolder with a random name composed of digits.

[image]

You will find an `.m4v` file there, for example, if you encode with x264. The `Previews` folder will be cleared every time you open Handbrake. If you close Handbrake, the file will stay there.